# Количество уникальных значений

Tags: mysql

> Вопрос по типу сделайте всё за меня

Есть таблица `search` в ней есть три поля

```
id|query|count
1 |ололо|0
2 |ололо|0
3 |ололо|0
4 |лолол|0
7 |лолол|0
9 |троло|0
```

Нужно получить такое

```
id|query|count
1 |ололо|3
4 |лолол|2
9 |троло|1
```

Проще говоря сделать поле `query` уникальным, и кол-во не уникальных значений вместе с уникальным запилить в поле `count`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще - так

```
SELECT min( id ) AS id, query, count(*) FROM search GROUP BY query
```

Советую почитать про агрегатные функции SQL

Comment: А можете на пальцах объяснить что и как происходит в этом коде? Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Группируем, т.е. собираем все строки с одинаковым значением поля `query` в одну.

При этом - высчитываем минимальное значение поля `id` и кол-во строк подходящих под условие